# Calling functions with arguments from within the function

Tags: r, function

I am writing a function where in one or more of the arguments are vectors generated by a loop within the function.
For ex:

```
 myfunc<-function(rep, n, arm1, arm2)
   {
   for(i in 1:rep)
    {
     x<-rnorm(n,0,4)
     y<-rnorm(n,0,5)
     res[i]<-t.test(arm1,arm2)
    }
   return(res)
   }
```

Now I would like to call the function as

```
     myfunc(rep = 10, n=10, arm1 = x, arm2 = x) or
     myfunc(rep = 10, n=10, arm1=x,arm2 = y)
```

The idea is compare different arms.

Hope I have stated my problem clearly.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your arm1 and arm2 arguments don't seem to be used in your function. Why don't you delete them and use `t.test(x,y)` ?

Comment: what is arm1/arm2? Why do you claim they are generated in the loop when they are not? Are arm1/2 supposed to play a role in generating x and y? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if I got it...

You want run `rep` tests, each with two vetors of `n` normal random variates. And you want to be able to change the arguments... Frankly, this is not the best way to program.. BUT, I will try to help you.

First things first: you can't assign to an arbitrary position of the result `res` before creating the variable. So I'll add `res <- list()` to your code. Also `t.test` returns more information, so it must be appended to a `list` object, with double square brackets.

Now, for the arguments, you must make R understand that `arm` are *symbol* arguments, to be evaluated inside the function's environment. So you must capture it's expression using `substitute` and pass it to `eval` function:

```
myfunc<-function(rep, n, arm1, arm2)  
{  
res <- list() ###  
for(i in 1:rep)  
{  
    x<-rnorm(n,0,4)  
    y<-rnorm(n,0,5)  
    res[[i]]<-t.test(eval(substitute(arm1)),eval(substitute(arm2))) ###  
}  
return(res)  
}
```

Try it...

A better way to do this is as follows:

```
newfunc <- function(rep, n, sd1, sd2)  
{  
lapply(1:rep, function(.) t.test(rnorm(n,0,sd1), rnorm(n,0,sd2)))  
}
```

Now `sd1` and `sd2` are the standard deviations parameters.